# Indoor Navigation with Google

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am looking into creating an ARKit wayfinding application based on this open source project: https://github.com/ashislaha/Route-Direction-in-AR

I have downloaded and compiled this code (changing the mode from 'driving' to 'walking') and have placed the point inside of a building that is supported by Google's indoor maps. All the levels are mapped out in Google, yet this application does not go indoors; even when 'walking' is selected, it still only sticks to roads and stops navigating at the door to my building.

My goal is to have the wayfinding indoors, using Google Maps indoor view, and have the overview_polyline give the overview of the route, all indoors, from one place in the building to another.

I was looking at GMSIndoorDisplay, but there seemed to be a lack of documentation surrounding it. Is this similar to what I'm looking for, or what would you guys recommend? Thanks!

Comment: I want to do the exam thing, did you have any success?